# How to make an https POST using JNI in Android?

Tags: android, https, java-native-interface

For an Android I would like to make https POST requests to a server using the java native interface.

Currently I get some values in `c` and passing them to the java part of the application where it posts them. I want to change that and make this part completely using `c` and then pass maybe a boolean if it succeeded or not through JNI. Yet I am stuck now as I am not sure how to proceed.
I have search for examples online but only found answers really old.

Comment: Why! You have working code. It's much harder from JNI.

Comment: @user207421 cause I already do some calculations using JNI and if I have to pass the result to java then it would be much easier for someone to reverse engineer this

Comment: If you use JNI to perform web operations (i.e. employ okhttp API or its alternatives), you don't protect your app from Java-side reverse engineering. If you are concerned about such threats, you can compile your native code with libcurl, and your web requests will be all pure C++, no JNI involved.

Comment: @AlexCohn thank you for the reply. Yes indeed i want to make all web request to be in C and just return to the application a boolean based on the success of this. How would I compile libcurl for android, some guides I have found are not very helpful for inexperienced users like me.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://github.com/gcesarmza/curl-android-ios) project on GitHub?

Comment: @AlexCohn compiled it now and the result is more than 30mb just for one architecture, which is way to big to include in a small application.

Comment: That's the size of libcurl.a or of your resulting .so ?

Comment: of the `libcurl.a` for `armeabi-v7a`

Comment: This does not mean your resulting binary must be that big. Try to use http POST and see what so,e is the linked so file